# Custom directive Attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my custom directive im getting attributes values, in my case it could be numbers or arrays, but in my directtive im getting a string array (ex: "[1,2]".

How can i get my array in the attribute not being a string?

view:

```
<div my-directive to=[1,2]
```

directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective',
        [
            '$http', '$q','$uibModal',
            dir
        ]);


function dir($http, $q, UserService, $uibModal) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            element.on( 'click', function( evt ){


                       console.log(attrs.to);

            });
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following approach:

**On view (init the directive & set the directive param)**

```
<div ng-app='demo'>
    <demo-directive to-val='[1,2,3,4,5]'></demo-directive>
</div>
```

**On the directive**

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
demo.directive('demoDirective', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-repeat="val in toVal">{{val}}</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            // parse the attribute array to a scope params
            scope.toVal = JSON.parse(attrs.toVal);
        }
    }
});
```